# Show children of a parent class Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, parent

I have a model for School and Student. Their relationship is School has_many Students. I am trying to render a view where if I am on the School index page and I click "Show", it will open up a new page and display a list of students that belong to that school. Ex:

```
School
- Student1
- Student2
- Student3
```

Comment: `@students = Student.where(school_id: params[:school_id])` should do it

Comment: What have you tried or what part are you stuck on? Do you have routes and a StudentsController created already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
# students controller
def index
  @students = Student.scoped
  @students = @students.where(school_id: params[:school_id]) if params[:school_id].present?
end

# view of the schools index
- @schools.each do |school|
  = link_to "students of the school #{school.id}", students_path(school_id: school.id)
```

Don't hesitate to ask for explanations if you don't fully understand ;)