# Render children of parent rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render

I have a Contract model that has_many Task_Orders. I am trying to render a view where if I click "Show" for Contract line item, it will display a list of Task_Orders that belong to that Contract.

Here is my Contract schema:

```
create_table "contracts", force: true do |t|
t.string   "contractId"
t.string   "contractName"
```

Here is my Task Order schema:

```
create_table "task_orders", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "contract_Id",              limit: 255
t.string   "task_orderId"
t.string   "task_orderName"
```

Here is my Contract model:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :task_orders

end
```

Here is my Task Order model:

```
class TaskOrder < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :contract

end
```

I am not entirely sure how to work with the controller and view to make it happen.... please help. I am using Rails 4.0

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show children of a parent class Rails 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833091/show-children-of-a-parent-class-rails-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**foreign_key**

Firstly, you need to ensure your foreign_keys are assigned for your associations:

```
#app/models/task_order.rb
Class TaskOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :contract, primary_key: "contractID", foreign_key: "contract_Id"
end

#app/models/contract.rb
Class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :task_orders, primary_key: "contractID", foreign_key: "contract_Id"
end
```

--

**Controller**

This should allow you to call the required data from your controller:

```
#app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb
Class ContractsController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @contract = Contract.find params[:id]
    end
end

#app/views/contracts/show.html.erb
<% for order in @contract.task_orders do %>
   <%= order.id %>
<% end %>
```